# Exposing a Highland.js stream, but handling the end event internally

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, highland.js

I am reading data from a PostgreSQL database using Node.js:

```
const readFromDatabase = function (callback) {
  pg.connect('pg://…', (errConnect, client, disconnect) => {
    if (errConnect) {
      return callback(errConnect);
    }

    const query = client.query('SELECT * FROM …');

    // …
  });
};
```

The `query` object now is an event emitter that emits `row` events whenever a row is received. Additionally, it emits an `end` event once all rows have been read.

What I would like to do now is to wrap this event emitter into a Highland.js stream and hand this over to the caller of my function. Basically this should do the job:

```
const stream = highland('row', query);

callback(null, stream);
```

Unfortunately, I still need to call the `disconnect` function once all rows have been read, and I don't want the caller to care about this. So how can I hand out the stream while still be able to register a callback for the `end` event?

I have seen that Highland.js offers the [done](http://highlandjs.org/#done) function that does exactly what I need, but it also causes the stream to start flowing (which I do not want to do internally, that's up to my caller).

How can I solve this?

Comment: I believe you are asking the wrong question. You are trying to intercept a data stream instead of just piping the data further, because that's how streams work. Check out [pg-query-stream](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-query-stream). That will let you do `.pipe` directly into your `highland` stream, no interception is needed.

Comment: This only makes things more complicated IMHO: I still need to handle the `end` event internally, but now I have the event emitter, a Node.js stream, and a Highland.js stream…

Comment: Actually, this simplifies things, the data is channeled automatically. Provided that you still need that `highland` stream, since you already have a usable stream there.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#streaming) of how to stream and process data in an easy way.